# KeyError when the key exists

Tags: python, flask

I am new to python and don't know much. I am running into an issue with my **init**.py file. I am doing a flask application with the flask microblog tutorial and trying to do error handling by having emails sent automatically I think I followed everything correctly but I keep getting this large error message with the following

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Non-admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 197, in _run_module_as_main
return _run_code(code, main_globals, None,
File "C:\Users\Non-admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\runpy.py", line 87, in _run_code
exec(code, run_globals)
File "C:\Users\Non-admin\Desktop\Vagrant\python\python learning folder\python_projects\microblog\venv\Scripts\flask.exe\__main__.py", line 7, in <module>
File "c:\users\non-admin\desktop\vagrant\python\python learning folder\python_projects\microblog\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 990, in main
cli.main(args=sys.argv[1:])
File "c:\users\non-admin\desktop\vagrant\python\python learning folder\python_projects\microblog\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 596, in main
return super().main(*args, **kwargs)
File "c:\users\non-admin\desktop\vagrant\python\python learning folder\python_projects\microblog\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1062, in main
rv = self.invoke(ctx)
File "c:\users\non-admin\desktop\vagrant\python\python learning folder\python_projects\microblog\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1668, in invoke
return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))     
File "c:\users\non-admin\desktop\vagrant\python\python learning folder\python_projects\microblog\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 1404, in invoke
return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
File "c:\users\non-admin\desktop\vagrant\python\python learning folder\python_projects\microblog\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 763, in invoke
return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
File "c:\users\non-admin\desktop\vagrant\python\python learning folder\python_projects\microblog\venv\lib\site-packages\click\decorators.py", line 84, in new_func
return ctx.invoke(f, obj, *args, **kwargs)
File "c:\users\non-admin\desktop\vagrant\python\python learning folder\python_projects\microblog\venv\lib\site-packages\click\core.py", line 763, in invoke
return __callback(*args, **kwargs)
File "c:\users\non-admin\desktop\vagrant\python\python learning folder\python_projects\microblog\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 845, in run_command
app = DispatchingApp(info.load_app, use_eager_loading=eager_loading)
File "c:\users\non-admin\desktop\vagrant\python\python learning folder\python_projects\microblog\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 321, in __init__
self._load_unlocked()
File "c:\users\non-admin\desktop\vagrant\python\python learning folder\python_projects\microblog\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 346, in _load_unlocked
self._app = rv = self.loader()
File "c:\users\non-admin\desktop\vagrant\python\python learning folder\python_projects\microblog\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 402, in load_app
app = locate_app(self, import_name, name)
File "c:\users\non-admin\desktop\vagrant\python\python learning folder\python_projects\microblog\venv\lib\site-packages\flask\cli.py", line 256, in locate_app
__import__(module_name)
File "C:\Users\Non-admin\Desktop\Vagrant\python\python learning folder\python_projects\microblog\app\__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
if app.config['MAIL_SERVER']:
   KeyError: 'MAIL_SERVER'
```

To the best of my understanding the key exists because in the config.py file I am specifying the keys with the get() method. I know I might be doing this wrong Please assist. BELOW is **config**.py

```py
import os

basedir = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

class Config(object):
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ.get('SECRET_KEY') or 'you-will-never-guess'
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI = os.environ.get('DATABASE_URL', '').replace or \
        'sqlite:///' + os.path.join(basedir, 'app.db')
    SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS = False
    MAIL_SERVER = os.environ.get('MAIL_SERVER')
    MAIL_PORT = int(os.environ.get('MAIL_PORT') or 25)
    MAIL_USE_TLS = os.environ.get('MAIL_USE_TLS') is not None
    MAIL_USERNAME = os.environ.get('MAIL_USERNAME')
    MAIL_PASSWORD = os.environ.get('MAIL_PASSWORD')
    ADMINS = ['admin@example.com']
```

Below is **init**.py where I am getting the error after I do flask run in the windows Command line. If I need to clarify more please let me know!

```
import logging
from logging.handlers import SMTPHandler, RotatingFileHandler
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_migrate import Migrate
from flask_login import LoginManager
from config import Config

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(Config)
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
migrate = Migrate(app, db)
login = LoginManager(app)
login.login_view = 'login'

**if not app.debug:
    if app.config['MAIL_SERVER']:**
    auth = None
    if app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] or app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD']:
        auth = (app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'], app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'])
    secure = None
    if app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS']:
        secure = ()
    mail_handler = SMTPHandler(
        mailhost=(app.config['MAIL_SERVER'], app.config['MAIL_PORT']),
        fromaddr='no-reply@' + app.config['MAIL_SERVER'],
        toaddrs=app.config['ADMINS'], subject='Microblog Failure',
        credentials=auth, secure=secure)
    mail_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    app.logger.addHandler(mail_handler)
```

Comment: Are you looking to have a dictionary or a class with instance variables?

Comment: yes I think so? I am super nooby so trial and erroring it lol

Comment: do a `print(os.environ.get('MAIL_SERVER')` directly below `MAIL_SERVER = os.environ.get('MAIL_SERVER')`. I think this value might not be set.

Comment: "To the best of my understanding the key exists because in the config.py file I am specifying the keys with the get() method. " Well, did you try explicitly verifying this? For example, did you try writing code to show you the entire dictionary, to see what keys are in it? Did you try using a debugger, to verify that the `MAIL_SERVER = os.environ.get('MAIL_SERVER')` line of code is reached? Did you try checking the value of `app.config` immediately before and immediately after the `from_config` call?

Answer (score 0):

```
MAIL_SERVER = os.environ.get('MAIL_SERVER')
```

`MAIL_SERVER` can be `None` after the line above was executed.

As a result the line above

```
app.config['MAIL_SERVER']
```

will throw `KeyError`.

*Solutions*

- Use `get` and handle the situation when a `None` is returned
- Use `get` with a proper default value (if there is one..)

Comment: Does `from_config` refuse to create keys with `None` values? I can't find anything in the documentation about that.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel Did you mean `from_object` ?

Comment: Yes, that one. I need more caffeine.